# I need to flip a div on hover

Tags: jquery

I am using [flip](http://lab.smashup.it/flip) plugin of jquery. I would like to flip a card(div), after it finished to flip, immediately to revertFlip it. That's what I tried

```
  $("#flipbox").bind("hover",function(){
    $(this).flip({
        direction:'tb',
        onEnd: function() {
            $(this).revertFlip();
            console.log('when the animation has already ended');

        }
    })
}
```

Comment: could you try and recreate it on jsfiddle?

Comment: Does it flip but not flip back, or doesn't it flip at all?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/netwire88/NAbZT/16/

```
$(document).on("click", ".flipbox-forward", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.flip({
        direction: $this.data("direction"),
        color: $this.data("color"),
        content: $this.data("title"),
        onBefore: function() {
            $this.removeClass('flipbox-forward');
            $this.addClass('flipbox-revert');
        }
    })
});

$(document).on("click", ".flipbox-revert", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.revertFlip();
    $this.removeClass('flipbox-revert');
    $this.addClass('flipbox-forward');
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

try to cheat.
Make 2 different classes,

then use the `mouseenter` event to change class and change it back with the `mouseleave` event.

at least, thats the kind of stuff I do when im close to my deadlines :P